# How to get directive's scope value to the controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have the directive that find the elements height and need to have the same value to the controller from the directive. 
I tried the below mentioned code and i could not find the solution, am facing some issues.

Could anyone help me on this?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myModule">
   <div myDirective style="height: 300px;" ng-controller="myheight">
     {{numvalue()}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js for directive

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.height = element.prop('offsetHeight');
            scope.width = element.prop('offsetWidth');
        }
    };
  })
;
```

contoller.js for controller

```
angular.module('myModule', []).controller("myheight", function($scope){

    $scope.numvalue = function(){

        $scope.divHeight  =  $scope.height;

        return $scope.divHeight;

    }

});
```

Comment: where is directive in html code?

Comment: @ngLover,  please see my updated code..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need $scope.numvalue();

Your directive looks fine. Just add it to the html and change code to following.

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div style="height: 300px;" my-directive ng-controller="myHeight">
    Getting height {{height}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re3j7scs/)

--EDIT--

Check the updated fiddle

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re3j7scs/1/)

Comment: I need to have this height value to my controller i need to do some operation over there. any help pls

Answer (score 0):

just expose a varible of controller to the directive. after compilation process of the directive you can access the scope variable `divHeight` in your controller.

```
  angular.module('myModule', [])
      .directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope:{
              divHeight: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element) {
                scope.divHeight = element.prop('offsetHeight');
                scope.width = element.prop('offsetWidth');
            }
        };
      });
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myModule">
   <div myDirective div-Height="divHeight" style="height: 300px;" ng-controller="myheight">
     {{numvalue()}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you have used 'div-Height="divHeight"' and could you please let me know what is the use of it?

Comment: it means i'm passing a variable from directive to controller if i change value in directive it will be reflected same as in controller